# How to use Type as a parameter but restrict it to a base class at compile time

Tags: c#

When a user changes an answer to a question, I want them to specify the reason from a set of reasons, and depending on the reason chosen, I want to create a specific subclass. So I want to hold the type to create in the `ChangeReason` class. I can do it like this, checking that the type is specified correctly at run-time:

```
public class ChangeReason
{
    Type _TypeToCreate;      

    public void SetQuestionType(Type value)
    {
        if (!value.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseAnsweredQuestion)))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid Type"); 

        _TypeToCreate = value;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to restrict the type at compile time, perhaps using a generic method? I'd like to call it like this:

```
var reason = new ChangeReason();
reason.SetQuestionType(typeof(AnsweredQuestion));
```

Comment: This is easily answered by googling "c# restrict generic type"... See the [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)

Comment: Disappointed by the downvote, After hitting a barrier trying to get to grips with generics I was reaching out for help, and I'm surprised that anyone thinks this question could be described as an "egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post". https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A generic method definition has a placeholder for the type e.g. `<T>`. This is the type parameter or argument. 
It is a way of making the method type safe, and the type argument can be accessed from inside the method. There is therefore no need to pass the type as a method argument.

Generic methods can be restricted to a specified base class or derivatives of that base class by adding a constraint: `where T : <base class name>`.

And if the base class is abstract, adding the `new()` constraint also prevents the base type being used.

```
public void SetQuestionType<T>() where T: BaseAnsweredQuestion, new()
{
    _TypeToCreate = typeof(T);
}
```

And then you can call it using:

```
reason.SetQuestionType<AnsweredQuestion>();
```

instead of:

```
reason.SetQuestionType(typeof(AnsweredQuestion));
```